# Unbounded operator with no bounded extension.

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R^d}$, $g \in L^\infty(X)$, and $p \in [1,\infty]$. Define the operator $T_g:L^p(X) \rightarrow L^p(X)$ by $f \mapsto fg$. Suppose that $T_g$ is injective but not surjective and show that $T_g^{-1}: \text{range}(T_g) \rightarrow L^p(X)$ is not bounded and that there is no bounded extension of $T_g^{-1}$ to $L^p(X)$.

I know that we can prove the first bit by showing that the $\text{range}(T_g)$ is a dense and proper subset of $L^p(X)$ and this will show that $T_g^{-1}$ is not bounded. However, I am not sure how to show that it is dense. I have looked at questions similar to this part on here but none seem to use the argument I am going for here. The proper subset is given to us by assumption. As for the existence of a bounded extension, how does one usually go about these arguments? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Idea: If it did have a bounded extension, you'd have a uniform bound $\| f/g\|_{L^p} \leq \| f\|_{L^p}$ for $f$ in a dense class; this'd imply that $1/g\in L^\infty$ and thus, that $T_g$ is surjective.

Comment: If an operator is not bounded it cannot have any bounded extension.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, this helps understand the bounded extension bit. Does anyone have any input for the density of the range bit?

Comment: An extension only adds to the domain,  ergo an extension to a linear operator can only increase (or not change) its norm as you are taking a $\sup$ over a larger set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T\in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$. Let $T^\star$ be the adjoint of $T$.
   Then

(1) $T$ is an isomorphism into $Y$ if and only if $T^\star$ is onto.

(2) $T^\star$ is an isomorphism into $X^\star$ if and only if $T$ is onto.

(3) $T$ is an isomorphism onto if and only if $T^\star$ is an isomorphism onto.

For a proof, see, for example, [Banach Space Theory](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-7515-7.pdf) Exercise 2.49 on p. 78 (note that (1)+(2) imply (3)).

2. If $1\leq p<+\infty$. Suppose that $T_g^{-1}:gf\in T_g(L^p(X))  \mapsto f\in L^p(X)$ is bounded. Then
   $T_g$ is an isomorphism from $L^p(X)$ into $T_g(L^p(X))$. According to step 1-(1),
   $T_g^\star$ is onto, but
   $$T_g^\star : h\in L^q(X)\mapsto gh\in L^q(X),$$
   where $q$ is the conjugate
   exponent of $p$.
   It follows that $\forall f\in L^q(X)$, $\exists h\in L^q(X)$ such that $f=gh$. Note that
   $g\neq 0$ a.e. (Indeed, if $\mu(\{g=0\})>0$, since $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $\sigma$-finite,
   we can find a set $A\subset \{g=0\}$ with $0<\mu(A)<+\infty$, let $f= 1_A\in L^q(X)$, then
   there doesn't exist an $h\in L^q$ such that $f=gh$, a contradiction.) Hence,
   For any $f\in L^q(X)$, $h= \frac{f}{g}$ is unique. Hence, $T_g^\star$ is bijective.
   According to step 1-(3), $T_g$ is surjective, a contradiction.
3. If $p=+\infty$.
   Define $$\widetilde{T}_g: f\in L^1(X)\mapsto gf\in L^1(X).$$
   Then $\widetilde{T}_g^\star =T_g$. The proof is entirely analogous.

---

**Another solution:**

$T_g^{-1}$ is continuous iff there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\|T_gf\|_{L^p(X)} \geq c \|f\|_{L^p(X)}$ for all $f\in L^p(X)$,
to put it another way,
$T_g^{-1}$ is not continuous iff there is a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}\subset L^p(X)$ with $\|f_n\|_{L^p(X)}=1$ such that
$T_gf_n = gf_n \to 0$ in $L^p(X)$. So, our purpose is to find such a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$.

Since $T_g$ is injective, we obtain that $g\neq 0$ a.e. on $X$.
Note that $\frac{1}{g}\notin L^\infty(X)$, otherwise $T_g$ is bijective. That means, there doesn't exist a constant $c>0$ such that
$\left|\frac{1}{g}\right|\leq c$ (or $|g|\geq \frac{1}{c}$) a.e. on $X$. Hence, for each $n$, we can find
a measurable subset $S_n \subset X$ with
$\mu(S_n)>0$ such that $|g|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ a.e. on $S_n$. Since $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $\sigma$-finite,
we can assume that $\mu(S_n)<+\infty$.

For each $n$, we can find a measurable function $f_n \in L^p(S_n)$ such that $\|f_n\|_{L^p(S_n)}=1$ (this is possible since we can use those simple functions).
Extend $f_n$  by $0$ outside $S_n$. Also,
$$\|T_gf_n\|_{L^p(X)}= \|gf_n\|_{L^p(X)}= \|gf_n\|_{L^p(S_n)}\leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \|f_n\|_{L^p(S_n)}=\frac1n\to 0 \quad \text{as $n\to\infty$}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I was thinking of constructing a sequence of the following form. Let $f \in L^p(E)$ and define $f_n = \chi_{\{x:|\phi| \geq n\}} \frac{f}{\phi}$, I am trying to show that the image of this sequence under $T_g$ converges to $f$. Would this type of argument work?

Comment: @Blaze I find another method, which is based on real analysis, see above.

Comment: Great answers, thank you. Do you know if the way I was going about it was salvageable? I think if you use the functions I mentioned we can get to the point where $\int_{\{x:|\phi| \leq n\}} |f|^p$. Is there a way I can argue that this integral can be made arbitrarily small?